# How to create a basic semantic search in python

Tags: python, search-engine, semantics, rdf, semantic-web

I want to write a basic semantic web crawler using Python, I know that semantic apps use RDF files, but what else? I have some Python RDF modules installed and I started learning how they work.

Could you introduce me to the technologies and techniques used in a semantic application?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The next things you might want to learn are:

- embedding samantic data in HTML - [RDFa](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdfa-syntax/), [microformats](http://microformats.org), [microdata](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microdata_%28HTML5%29). Some stats: microformats and RDFa deployment across the Web via [DAM.co.uk](http://digitalassetmanagement.org.uk/2011/01/26/microformats-and-rdfa-deployment-across-the-web/):
  [image: Microformats and RDFa deployment across the Web]
- querying RDF data - [SPARQL](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-sparql-query/)
- [most popular ontologies](http://richard.cyganiak.de/blog/2011/02/top-100-most-popular-rdf-namespace-prefixes/) currently in use
- list of [available SPARQL endpoints](http://www.w3.org/wiki/SparqlEndpoints)

You can find some examples of SPARQL queries [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sparql). Another notable Q&A resource is [semanticweb.com](http://answers.semanticweb.com/).

Comment: thank you sir so much, you gave me much more information than what i expected! Thanks a lot :P