# How to create a mobile version of a video hosting site

Tags: php, iphone, android, html, mobile

I've been googling for about 2 month on how to create a mobile website and found many results which work great if you have a blog or anything like that. But I have some sort of a video hosting site and i need to allow users to watch, upload and rate videos. i have jw player player and the script is php javascript

when I say mobile i mean everything from smartphone to android, everything

Any help or a link for a tutorial would be highly appreciated

**EDIT**

@Bizorke I'm not asking you to write me a book, i want an answer [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6974900/how-to-create-a-basic-semantic-search-in-python)

That guy answered a huge question with one small paragraph and some tutorials that's it and I loved his answer

and i would read any book if you suggest one, because i cannot find a good one

Comment: you say that this question should be closed, I'll delete it right now if you tell me why it should be closed - you voted it down

Comment: i know the rules here - it's never been asked before and I can't find the answer anywhere so it's not a possible duplicate of another question - it's related to programming and it's not vague - i need to know how to stream and let users upload on mobile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Edited in response to comments*

I can try giving you a starting point for your project. If you want to know how this can be done, stop searching for an answer online and start looking for a very detailed book on mobile web development. There are a lot of things to learn, especially if you are trying to build a cross-platform mobile website. There are lots of books out there, you'll need to find some that talk about cross-platform mobile web development. A lot of experimentation will be required.

For the actual video sharing part I would just develop the site to work exactly the same as such a website would work for a PC. Mobile devices are becoming increasingly similar to PCs in terms of power and browsing experience, so you might just be able to do this part with minimal hassle if you're lucky. After you've completed the site and it works on a PC, just go back and test it with a whole bunch of different types of mobile devices to see which phones support it and which don't, and go from there by customizing the website to work with different specific types of devices.

Good luck!

*Additional Information*

I have done some mobile app dev before but never a mobile website, so can't offer any good suggestions for books (google books has a bunch listed but you'll have to look at the descriptions to find a good one that suits your needs and interests).

Also, have you considered making a mobile app to accomplish what you are trying to do? You could build an app for each type of smartphone, then you won't have to worry about platform browser compatibility issues.

Comment: and I cannot find no real book, could you suggest a book sir?

Comment: I considered mobile app but I don't know objective C for Iphone, lets say i use flash, better than java for video hosting site i guess, I would have to figure out to connect my app to my site, and i guess i have to create about 3 apps for all mobiles, that seems like ALOT of work for one guy lol...mission impossible :D and i can't do it, I'm not Tom Cruise :)

Comment: I'm not sure this is a good answer. You can get this kind of answers from any person walking down the street. The worst part is when @Bizorke recommends to build an app for each type of smartphone.